# Getting Undefined property: stdClass::$migration error in Lumen when making a migration

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I've built and run 1000 migrations with Laravel/Lumen and I've never seen this happen before. I'm running a dev copy of my application locally, I'm using sqlite with the latest Lumen.

This is what happens:

```
php artisan migrate
Migration table created successfully.

In Builder.php line 2364:

  Undefined property: stdClass::$migration
```

I've tried deleting the sqlite database and restarting. The weird thing is, even if I remove the migrations, I still get the error.

database.php

```
<?php

return [
    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
    'connections' => [
        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => env('DB_PREFIX', '')
        ],
        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
        'redis' => [
            'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis'),
            'default' => [
                'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
                'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
                'database' => env('REDIS_DB', 0),
            ],
        ]
    ]

];
```

bootstrap/app.php

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

(new Laravel\Lumen\Bootstrap\LoadEnvironmentVariables(
    dirname(__DIR__)
))->bootstrap();

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Create The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here we will load the environment and create the application instance
| that serves as the central piece of this framework. We'll use this
| application as an "IoC" container and router for this framework.
|
*/

$app = new Laravel\Lumen\Application(
    dirname(__DIR__)
);

$app->withFacades();
$app->withEloquent();

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Container Bindings
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Now we will register a few bindings in the service container. We will
| register the exception handler and the console kernel. You may add
| your own bindings here if you like or you can make another file.
|
*/

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
    App\Exceptions\Handler::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class,
    App\Console\Kernel::class
);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Middleware
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, we will register the middleware with the application. These can
| be global middleware that run before and after each request into a
| route or middleware that'll be assigned to some specific routes.
|
*/

// $app->middleware([
//     App\Http\Middleware\ExampleMiddleware::class
// ]);

// $app->routeMiddleware([
//     'auth' => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
// ]);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Service Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here we will register all of the application's service providers which
| are used to bind services into the container. Service providers are
| totally optional, so you are not required to uncomment this line.
|
*/

// $app->register(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class);
// $app->register(App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class);
// $app->register(App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class);
$app->register(Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class);
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Load The Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next we will include the routes file so that they can all be added to
| the application. This will provide all of the URLs the application
| can respond to, as well as the controllers that may handle them.
|
*/

$app->router->group([
    'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers',
], function ($router) {
    require __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php';
});

return $app;
```

Including `app/Console/Kernel.php` as well:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Laravel\Lumen\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can't help much without seeing *relevant* code

Comment: Which code do you want to see? This is a migration and it happens even if I remove the migrations.

Comment: Any artisan command goes through a bootstrapping process (usually kicked off by `App/Console/Kernel.php` in Laravel, not sure if Lumen is the same). If there's an error somewhere in this process then all commands will throw this error.

Comment: maybe try removing vendor and reinstalling everything with `composer install`

Comment: I blew away the `vendor` dir and reinstalled. No luck.

Comment: I edited my question above to include `database.php` and `bootstrap/app.php`

Comment: A bit more context; As @apokryfos suggests, the error should occur whenever a command is run, but that's not the case. It only seems to happen for migrations so far (for instance `php artisan cache:clear` doesn't produce an error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duh - I was missing `‘migrations’ => ‘db_migrations’,` in `database.php`

Answer (score 0):

**Modify the file `Illuminate\Database\Schema\Grammars\MySqlGrammar@compileColumnListing:`**

**Change:**

```
select column_name from information_schema.columns...
```

**To:**

```
select column_name as `column_name` from information_schema.columns ...
```

See the [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/20190) here.

Comment: That issue was from 2 years ago and it looks like it was fixed within the framework already as I have that change already integrated.